# PHP array search

Tags: php

I'm trying to add some quick and simple search functionality to a site. The site has an XML file with all their stores, and I want to create a search box to search for the closest store to the user by town or postcode.

I have put all the data into an array, but as far as I can tell, there is no way to 'search' an array (NOT array_search) to retrieve results like using a MySQL LIKE query.

Surely there must be a way? Using MySQL isn't an option in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Three options:

- As your source is XML, you could use QueryPath or phpQuery to filter the initial data set.
- If MySQL is not an option, you could still use a SQLite in-memory database, if you really want to use LIKE.
- Or time tested and most simple: just manually loop over your array and do manual comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

You can try *array_filter()* with an user defined callback.

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet here is to actually load the XML into a DOM object (DOMDocument or SimpleXML) and then use its XPath impelemntation. Its not SQL but its a lot less work than writing your own algorithm that consumes the array. Especially if you are talking about performing real distance calculations like you might with an SQL platform.

Comment: When using XPath be careful about namespaces, you usually can't set default namespace for xpath so tags in xpath have to be prefixed with default namespace of xml (it there is some defined in that xml).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like LINQ but in a PHP environment. Unfortunately I don't know of any solution like this. Best solution I can see is a custom search with a foreach and your own search parameters. Or just store the information in SQL and avoid trying to emulate it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$q = $_GET['search'];

$file = new DOMDocument();
$file->load("filename.xml");

$xml = simplexml_import_dom($file);
foreach($xml->store as $store) 
{
  $store_name = $store->name;
  if($q == $store_name)
  {
    //query in your database
  }
}
```